# How to calculate all numbers with percentage in a string?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on logic for my calculator. How do I replace all numbers with `%` with an actual value in a string format?

For example:

```
const foo = "5%+5%+123+6%"
```

into

```
0.05 + 0.05 + 123 + 0.06
```

so if I used `eval()` function it would calculate and the output would be:

```
130.43565
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.replaceAll` with `eval`

Replace `%` with `/100` and use `eval` on the replaced string

```js
const foo = "5%+5%+123+6%";
const replacedString = foo.replaceAll('%', '/100');
console.log(eval(replacedString));
```

Comment: NICE!! YOU MADE MY LONG CODE INTO A SINGLE LINE! THANK YOU SO MUCH! But why is 123 times 6 percent is equal to 130.38 and mine returns 123.06?

Comment: Can you post the expression as the string?

Comment: Here is the replaced percent with "/100" - 5/100+5/100+123+6/100. If I input from another calculator as 123+6% it equals to 130.68 but I exchange places, it returns 123.06. From mine, regardless of the position, it returns the same.

Comment: @AlmightyDee I didnot get the issue,  5/100+5/100+123+6/10 = 0.05 + 0.05 + 123 + 0.06 = 123.16 this is correct only. What is the issue in this calculation?

Comment: Thank you for the response! Technically right, but I gotta add some logic to it. I understand now why it returns different depending on the position of expression. God bless!!